# Laravel/Lumen: validating and redirecting (302)

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am tryng to validate my post input by:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

and this redirects me to my base url which is odd.

I would expect some error if not valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was using API call, I have changed my request to:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'
    ]);
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not what is redirecting you, it's likely Laravel is just halting because of an error.

You may need to change `$request` to `$request->all()` though - that may be the cause of your error. Edit: looks like the new Docs state you don't need the ->all() method afterall.

You can check for errors on the Validator class with this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  // catch errors here - error messages can be accessed via: $validator->messages();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will check it.